# Linux thread with mutex

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, mutex

Hi I have program which simulate horse farm, there are some place with food and some horses, horse eats food. If there are not food horse give signal to farmer and he add more food.

Here is my c program:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM 5

pthread_cond_t cond= PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

long food;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

pthread_t horse[NUM];

pthread_t farmar;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;


void * funHorse(void *);
void * funFarmar(void *);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

  food = 10;

  pthread_cond_init(&(cond), NULL);

  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
    pthread_create(&horse[i], NULL, funHorse,(void *) &i);
  }
  pthread_create(&farmar, NULL, funFarmar, NULL);

  printf("Join farmar\n");
  pthread_join(farmar, NULL);

  for(i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
    printf("Join horse\n");
    pthread_join(horse[i], NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}

void * funHorse(void * param){

   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   int index = *((int*) param);
   food--;
   printf("Eating horse number %d there are %d food \n",index,food);
   sleep(1);
   if(food == 0){
     printf("Horse number %d is hungry\n",index);
     pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
   }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}


void * funFarmar(void * param){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  printf("Sleeping\n");
  pthread_cond_wait(&(cond),&(mutex));

  food = 20;
  printf("There are %d food \n",food);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

There is problem that horses eats only 5 times. Do not know why. If i change initialization of food to `food = 2` ... result at the end is -3 (farmer does not add food).

I want to infinity loop of eating by horses and adding food by farmer.

Comment: I don't really think you want `pthread_join` , not like you used it.

Comment: you need an infinite loop before calling pthread_join

Comment: You will want to add a loop inside your thread functions `funKobyla` (so the horse doesn't just eat once and then stops) and `funFarmar` (so the farmer doesn't just add food once and then stop). Your horse should probably also check whether there is food available BEFORE it eats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `cond` twice: `pthread_cond_t cond= PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;` and `pthread_cond_init(&(cond), NULL);`. Just remove the second one.

You do not initialize `mutex`: `pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` should do the job. You have the `mutex` variable twice, remove one.

You pass the address of `i` to the threads, but the main thread change `i`. You should create an array and pass each thread another number from this array.

```
int number[NUM];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
  number[i]=i;
  pthread_create(&horse[i], NULL, funHorse,&number[i]);
}
```

you forgot to `return` something in the threads.

This should solve your programming errors.